# $(document).ready and iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Will

```
$(document).ready
```

in parent page wait for iframe content to be loaded completely?

I have a parent page in which there is a an iFrame. After the iFrame is completely loaded I need to invoke a function in the iFrame from the parent page.

Answer (score 4):

I've been the whole day breaking my balls to find this, I needed it for the work.

Finally I've made my thing (A website with an iframe that loads the content of the links.
  All i wanted to do was to scroll the page to the top, with a button inside the iframe
And it seemed to be wizards work)

Well, that's what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('ifram#IframeID').load(function () { //The function below executes once the iframe has finished loading<---true dat, althoug Is coppypasta from I don't know where
     var varStoresNameIframe =$('iframe#IframeID').contents().find('.buttonsClass');
        $(varStoresNameIframe).click (function () {
            $('html , body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
        }); 
   });
});
```

Related link:

- [jQuery’s document ready() event and iframe](http://blog.cyandigital.com/2010/10/jquerys-document-ready-event-and-iframe/)

So the masterkey for me was the line:

```
$('ifram#IframeID').load(function () {
```