# Jquery iframe ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one iframe in my page and i'm submiting my form to that iframe so after iframe finished loading i need to fire a function each time iframe have finished loading contents.

I've tried using `ready` and `load` but nothing is working, can any one give me some example?

**EDIT** Also when i'm submiting my browser shows me that page is loading how can i remove that?

Comment: put your js/jquery in the iframe, not the parent

Comment: possible duplicate of [$(document).ready and iframe content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182031/document-ready-and-iframe-content)

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005/how-do-i-fire-an-event-when-a-iframe-has-finished-loading-in-jquery (see second answer). If not, say what's different from those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the function to be fired within the new iframe content

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                console.log('this is loaded');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        THE RESPONSE OF YOUR FORM ACTION
    </body>
    </html>
```

Or post your iframe code and we can try to fix it

No way to hide the fact the browser is loading new content when submitting, as long as I can see. **Have you tried to use a div instead** of the iframe? This would be mush easier IMHO and the loading would be hidden if I can remember right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i solved it with onload="" event now the only problem that's left is that browser is showing loading stuff, and no i can't use div i'm uploading files via iframe

Comment: so i can post my data to div?

Comment: I'm glad you solved one part of your goal. For the second part have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623361/how-to-hide-page-loading-transferring-data-indicators-and-spinners-caused-by

Comment: Of course you can by using ajax. Just google for an example. Type `Simple Ajax Example` and you will have some stuff

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options, depending on where your Javascript lives:

1. You can put your .ready() javascript on the iframe's **source webpage** (a good option if the parent webpage, the one that contains the iframe, doesn't need to know what events are going on inside the iframe):

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       console.log('My webpage loaded!');
   });
   ```
2. Or, you can put your .load() JS on the **parent webpage** like this:

   ```
   var win = document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow || iframe;
   $(win).load(function(){
       console.log('The iframe on my webpage loaded');
   });
   ```