# Show iframe first when content is loaded

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem. I can't figure out how I can load an iframe with jQuery or Ajax, and when the content is loaded inside the iframe, then output it to the page.

The problem is that, I am loading an external page on my web site, and sometimes the external page is very slow or does not load. If that happens I don't want the browser to keep trying to load the iframe on my web site, and I don't want a big blank space.

So I need to load an external page in a iframe, without the browser loads and first when or if the content is loaded, then the iframe is showed on the website. Is this possible?

Comment: `$('iframe').on('load', function() { $(this).show(); });`

Comment: Why do you want to load an iframe via ajax? Why don't you just have the iframe element inside your page?

Comment: This might get handy in case... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182031/document-ready-and-iframe-content

Answer (score 0):

Try with "on load" like

```
$('#my_iframe').on('load', function(){
    $(this).show(); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

put the iframe in the page:

```
<div id="theIframeContainer" style="display:none">
  <iframe src="theSite"></iframe>
<div>
```

then, jquery code

```
$(function() {
  $("#theIframeContainer").show();
}
```